# Service Bus Explorer - Lock Resources

Tags: azure, azureservicebus

I'd like to remove the delete capability from Service Bus Explorer.  I tried locking the resources at the Service Bus level but that only restricts deletion through the portal. I think Service Bus Explorer can still delete because it uses Manage claim permission to connect with.

Apart from removing the Delete button from Service Bus Explorer, is there a more elegant way to remove delete capability?

Thanks,

Richard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just as you've outlined, Service Bus Explorer is using the Manage claim which will always allow it to delete. This would need to be a feature implemented with the Service Bus Explorer. You could raise a feature request here: https://github.com/paolosalvatori/ServiceBusExplorer